# How to export standalone html/css with javascript from angular project?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I have an angular project with html's/CSS/component(.ts files)/service(.ts files).
service methods are reading data from .json files in the assets folder(not calling backend).

I am doing a prod build which will generate html's/CSS/javascript files in dist folder.

The problem is generated index.html file is not rendering, displaying blank screen in browser without server(application server). My requirement is to make this HTML work offline.

how can I export standalone html's/CSS/javascripts to work as a offline html from angular project?

Generated dist folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Did you look at the console? Any error? Is there any http requests fired that should not? You'll need to give us more details about this "blank page".

Comment: This is happen normally. You have to host your dist files inside a serve to view the application. In the development time we are normally using ``ng serve`` for this

Comment: @Gaël J, there is no error in the console. http request are fine(anyway these are static data from json file which is working fine).  the question is in general, how to convert angular project to convert to static set of files(html/js/css/json) which works without any server.

Comment: Understood, so far you are doing it right. The output of prod build can be used in a browser without any server if the code you wrote doesn't need any server. That's why we'd need more details

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) package.

First **install** the **package globally**

`npm install http-server -g`

Then inside your project directory(in the terminal) just run

`http-server dist/`

And if you are using Angular 6+ or above (Working with Angular 10), You have to run

`http-server dist/your-project-name`

Now you can visit http://localhost:8080 to view your application

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, we want this html/js/data to export and give it users, so that they can use it offline(without any server). is there any suggestion for this?